# Get Rolling Sum from one column and Max from another column based on da

Tags: mysql, sql

| Stores | Animals | Date | Qty (Sold/ Received) | Moving Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| QQQ | RAT | 12/28/2022 | 1 | 100 |
| QQQ | RAT | 12/31/2022 | -1 | 200 |
| BBB | RAT | 11/23/2022 | 3 | 50 |
| BBB | RAT | 11/28/2022 | 5 | 100 |
| BBB | RAT | 11/30/2022 | 3 | 800 |
| BBB | CAT | 12/27/2022 | 2 | 100 |
| BBB | CAT | 12/28/2022 | 1 | 90 |

So its just one table

| Stores | Animals | Cumulative Qty | Existing Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| QQQ | RAT | 1 | 100 |
| BBB | RAT | 11 | 100 |
| BBB | CAT | 3 | 90 |

I will manually put a effective date of 12/28/2022 and I should get above values.

| Stores | Animals | Cumulative Qty | Existing Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BBB | RAT | 11 | 100 |
|  |  |  |  |

I will manually put a effective date of 12/15/2022 and I should get above values.

Basically I want to Group By Column Stores and Animals and get the Cumulative Qty on that Date AND the Effective Price on that Date.

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vx78zQEPZnGV164ASRoG2c/0):

```
CREATE TABLE animal_transactions (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    store VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    animal VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    date DATE NOT NULL,
    quantity INT NOT NULL,
    moving_price DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL
);


INSERT INTO animal_transactions (store, animal, date, quantity, moving_price)
VALUES
    ('QQQ', 'RAT', '2022-12-28', 1, 100),
    ('QQQ', 'RAT', '2022-12-31', -1, 200),
    ('BBB', 'RAT', '2022-11-23', 3, 50),
    ('BBB', 'RAT', '2022-11-28', 5, 100),
    ('BBB', 'RAT', '2022-11-30', 3, 800),
    ('BBB', 'CAT', '2022-12-27', 2, 100),
    ('BBB', 'CAT', '2022-12-28', 1, 90);

WITH DataSource AS
(
  SELECT *
        ,SUM(quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY store, animal ORDER BY date) culm_quantity
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY store, animal ORDER BY date DESC) row_id
  FROM animal_transactions
 
)
SELECT *
FROM DataSource
WHERE row_id = 1
ORDER BY store, animal, date
```

[image]

The idea is to sum the quantities per store and animal ordering the records by date. Also at the same time, order the records marking the oldest one as first.

In order to filter the data by date, add WHERE clause in the CTE.

Comment: May be I missed to inform, but I just need a Select Query, without Insert  and no hardcoding

Comment: @VikasMayekar it is a `SELECT` query. The `INSERT` is to create your sample data.